Azure VMSS Custom Data refresh the exisiting VMs
I use Terraform to create VMSS as part of it i use custom data which i need to run before the instance is marked healthy. I use VMSS rolling strategy, And due to this the updates are in place and any change in custom data is not propagated to existing VMs. New VMs do come with the change.
I know Azure ask to re-image the VMSS to recreate all the VMs again. I just wanted to check is there a way re-image can be done through terraform or any other way using terraform which will destroy and recreate the instances once the changes are detected similar to AWS Autoscaling.

Any code you tried so far @Pravin?


Azure VMSS Custom Data refresh the existing VMs using terraform.

For this kind of requirement, you can use create_before_destroy  along with lifecycle rules and a null resource using commands which can trigger whenever there is a change in custom data.
This setup works as same as AWS Auto Scaling and meets the requikrement.
Configuration:
resource "null_resource" "vmss_reimage_trigger" {
  triggers = {
    
    custom_data_hash = filemd5("custom_data.sh")
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo 'Changes detected, will re-image VMSS'"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine_scale_set" "vmss" {
  name                = "vmss-demo"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  admin_username      = "adminuser"
  admin_password      = "P@55w0rd1234!"  
  sku                 = "Standard_F2"
  instances           = 1

  custom_data = base64encode(file("custom_data.sh"))

  os_disk {
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2019-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest" 
  }

  upgrade_mode = "Automatic"

  health_probe_id = azurerm_lb_probe.lb_probe.id

  automatic_instance_repair {
    enabled      = true
    grace_period = "PT10M"
  }

  network_interface {
    name    = "example"
    primary = true

    ip_configuration {
      name      = "internal"
      primary   = true
      subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.internal.id
      load_balancer_backend_address_pool_ids = [azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.bap.id]
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
  depends_on = [null_resource.vmss_reimage_trigger]  
}

Deployment:


refer:
azurerm_windows_virtual_machine_scale_set | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry
The lifecycle Meta-Argument - Configuration Language | Terraform | HashiCorp Developer
